# Boomerang decompiler fails

Tags: c++, decompiling, boomerang

I need to decompile a windows program which the source code was lost for a long time.

I am using boomerang in Windows 7 for this. However, it looks broken, gives this message and quits:

```
Could not open dynamic loader library Win32BinaryFile.dll (error #998)
```

Googling about it gives no useful results. Looking in the [boomerang source code](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/doxy/BinaryFileFactory_8cpp-source.html), it is apparently coming from this:

```
00137     hModule = LoadLibraryA(libName.c_str());
00138     if(hModule == NULL) {
00139         int err = GetLastError();
00140         fprintf( stderr, "Could not open dynamic loader library %s (error #%d)\n", libName.c_str(), err);
00141         fclose(f);
00142         return NULL;
00143     }
```

I.e. `LoadLibraryA` is failing with the status 998.

What could I do to fix that?

**Edit, four hours later:**

The program that I want to decompile is a work that me and a friend implemented in 2005. The source just gone in the mean time without we seeing that. Now, in 2013, when we searched it, nothing was found. In retrospect, it was probably lost in 2008 or in 2010, two occasions where my computer hardware crashed and I needed to get a new computer (and lost a lot of data with that). We had several backups scattered in several places, but after an exhaustive search, I found nothing.

I know that since boomerang is open source, I could just get its source code and hack it around. However, that sort of task is not what I originally intended to do, since the focus is just to decompile my program and I guess that I am missing something simple, since it can't load the DLL while it is clearly there.

I don't need the exact code back, just a sketch of what were the exact details of the algorithm that were implemented. Having that, I can rewrite the rest again.

Comment: The boomerang archive should contain Win32BinaryFile.dll. Check whether your installation includes the file, otherwise download it again.

Comment: It is there. I extracted the zip file from sourceforge in a folder C:\boomerang, including the 2 .exe files, the 11 .dll files and other files like .bmp images. The signature, frontend, output and test folders are there too.

Comment: The DllMain() function in the DLL crashed with an access violation.  It is open source so you could fix it, I guess.  Clearly you'd be focusing on the wrong task, good disassemblers cost money.